# Mac osx 10.6.6 jar-blunder not collecting main class from javaFX jar packages

Tags: jar, javafx-2, jarbundler

I am trying to make a Mac osX  app bundle using jar-blunder on mac 10.6.6.

** I am using default ant task of NetBeans on windows to build the Jar file.(developing the project on windows). then transfer the jar file to mac osX to create the App bundle.

When I working **with swing jar packages, The jar-blunder working** fine and collecting the main class as usual but when i working **with a javaFX jar, The jar-blunder not collecting the main class** from the jar file.

1. What is the solution?
2. **I do not want to use oracle's AppBundler** because it using JavaAppLauncher instead of JavaApplicationStub which resulting the app lunching failure on java 1.6

Thank you.

Comment: The [minimum supported OS X configuration is JavaFX 2.x OS X 10.7.3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) and it is only supported on Mac for JavaSE 7u6 and later.

Comment: I can run my javaFX jar(which is compiled in windows)on OS X 10.8.3 (using java 1.6.0_45) and it run fine. I want to create an App bundle for that jar. Unfortunately OS x 10.8.3 has no jarbundler . I think they removed it. So i am trying using 10.6.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution. A universal JavaApplicationStub which supports java 1.6 and upwards. 
https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub